# Add Download Button to R Blogdown Website

Tags: pdf, button, download, blogdown

I am looking for an approach to include links to PDF files on a R blogdown built website. Is there any easy approach that I can follow? Please, help!

Answer (score 1):

You can put the PDF file in [the `static/` folder](https://bookdown.org/yihui/blogdown/static-files.html) (e.g., `static/files/document.pdf`), and use the link `[Download file](/files/document.pdf)` in your Markdown source.